# About a proof of Intermediate-value theorem for real continuous functions ("Mathematical Analysis Second Edition" by Tom M. Apostol)

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am reading "Mathematical Analysis Second Edition" by Tom M. Apostol.

> ***Theorem 4.38 (Intermediate-value theorem for real continuous functions).*** *Let $f$ be real-valued and continuous on a connected subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $f$ takes on two different values in $S$, say $a$ and $b$, then for each real $c$ between $a$ and $b$ there exists a point $x$ in $S$ such that $f(x)=c$.*

> *Proof.* The image $f(S)$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^1$. Hence, $f(S)$ is an interval containing $a$ and $b$ (see Exercise 4.38). If some value $c$ between $a$ and $b$ were not in $f(S)$, then $f(S)$ would be disconnected.

If $f(S)$ is an interval containing $a$ and $b$, then $f(S)$ contains any real number $c$ between $a$ and $b$ because $f(S)$ is an interval.
Why did the author write the following sentence?
The author wrote $f(S)$ is an interval and we prove the fact $f(S)$ is an interval in Exercise 4.38.
So, I think we can use the fact $f(S)$ is an interval.

> If some value $c$ between $a$ and $b$ were not in $f(S)$, then $f(S)$ would be disconnected.

I think the above sentence is true, but I feel this sentence is strange in this place.

Is the above sentence a proof of the fact that $f(S)$ is an interval?

Comment: No, the proof that a connected subset of $\mathbb{R} $ must be an interval is handled in an exercise.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Then, why did the author write the last sentence?

Comment: The author just wrote the fact which we must prove in Exercise 4.38?

Comment: Well Apostol says that if some point $c$ between $a, b $ does not lie in $f(S) $ then $f(S) $ would not be an interval (by definition of interval) and then it would be disconnected (contra positive of exercise mentioned by Apostol).

Comment: And yes you must prove the exercise if you want to complete the proof.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Then again, it is more immediate to show that $c\not f(S)$ leads to disconnectedness (and this is exactly the way one shows the exercise result the author wants to use here)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the proof of the intermediate-value theorem we do not need to know that $f(S)$ is an interval. The argument is simple:

If some value $c$ between $a$ and $b$ were not in $f(S)$, then  $f(S) \cap (-\infty,c)$ and $f(S) \cap (c,\infty)$ would form a partition of $f(S)$ into disjoint non-empty open subsets so that $f(S)$ would be disconnected.

This argument can also be used to prove that all connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ must be intervals. Concerning the converse, Apostol has proved that open intervals are connected after Theorem 3.11.

In fact all intervals are connected, but Apostol left this as an exercise.

Comment: Paul Frost, Thank you very much for your answer.